# Ruby on Rails: Pass Parameters to View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, parameters

When a user makes a request to the url /mobile in my Rails app, I would like a parameter to automatically be appended to the URL that gets loaded after the request (something like `/mobile?tree_width=5`)

I have tried a few things, all of which have not worked.

The closest I have gotten is this in my controller:

```
  def mobile
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html{
             # pass tree width here
             render mobile_project_steps_path(@project, :tree_width => @project.tree_width)
        }        
    end
  end
```

I am getting the error

```
Missing template /projects/8/steps/mobile?tree_width=5
```

But I think this path should exist according to my rake routes:

```
mobile_project_steps GET      /projects/:project_id/steps/mobile(.:format)                    steps#mobile
```

How do I add a param to the URL from a controller?

Comment: Did you meant to `redirect_to` rather than `render`?

Comment: @BroiSatse if I use redirect_to, I get a redirect loop

Comment: Because you need a condition, will write an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the param is missing and if it is redirect to current action with extra param. I would squeeze it with in before_action:

```
  before_action :check_tree_width, only: :mobile

  def mobile
    # Your actual logic
  end

  private

  def check_tree_width
    redirect_to(tree_width: @project.tree_width) unless params[:tree_width].present?
  end
```